# Linear prediction of weakly stationary stochastic process

Tags: stochastic-processes, time-series

Let $X\{(n)\}_{n\in \mathbb Z}$ be a weakly stationary stochastic process.

Given the information up to time $n$, $\{X_k\vert k\leq n\}$, in what way does the optimal linear predition change when I ask for the best linear predictor for $X(n+l),l>1$ instead of $X(n+1)$?

Intuitively, they should be the same, since I don't gain any information, I just try to look further into the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The optimal predictor depends on the prediction length $l$. To see this, define the prediction error

$$\epsilon_k = X_k - \sum_{m=0}^{\infty}w_m X_{k-l-m}$$

where $w_k$ are the coefficients of the prediction filter. If you use the common MSE criterion you get

$$E\{\epsilon_k^2\} \rightarrow \min_{w_k}$$

where $E\{\cdot\}$ denotes the expectation operator.
This leads to the orthogonality condition

$$E\{\epsilon_kX_{k-l-n}\}=0 \text{ for } n\ge 0 $$

which is equivalent to

$$\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}w_mr_X(n-m)=r_X(n+l)\text{ for } n\ge 0 \tag{1}$$

where $r_X(n)$ is the autocorrelation function of $X_k$.
From (1), the optimal coefficients $w_k$ can be computed. Note that they depend on the prediction length $l$.